# Is there any way to resolve mvn clean package error

Tags: spring

rying to run this in studio facing and error
[image]

[below is the pom.xml file]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpsapi2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>httpsapi2</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <app.runtime>4.3.0-20210322</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.5.1</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration><failOnError>false</failOnError></configuration>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        
   
        <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>false</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.24</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-spring-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v2</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

[below is mule artifact.json file]

```
 {
  "minMuleVersion": "4.3.0",
  "secureProperties": ["db.password","sf.password","sf.token","sf.consumer_secret","email.password","cloudhub.password"],
   "classLoaderModelLoaderDescriptor": {
        "id": "mule",
        "attributes": {
        "exportedPackages":[
   "com.java.muleinuse"
   ],
            "exportedResources": [
                "beans.xml"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[I'm trying to authenticate HTTPS API using spring beans in any point studio but facing an error while running the project .As I'm new to mule I tried all my means to resolve this issue but couldn't, is there any other way]

Comment: Looks like any point studio isn’t installed correctly on your system. Also try closing the Studio then try mvn clean package from command line on the project directory

Answer (score 0):

Unknown packaging:
`<packaging>mule-application</packaging>`

you need to pick one of correct ones

jar, war, ear, pom, maven-plugin, ejb, rar, msi, rpm, tar, tar.bz2, tar.gz, tbz, zip

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#packaging

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).